# Tweak Gnome with Python

Tags: python, linux, pygtk, gnome

I'd like to change the default behavior of some windows in gnome. I'd like to use python for this. So far I've only found pygtk tutorial but that's not what I actually want. I'd like to find something like "get list of open windows", "handle mount click on selected window" etc. Could you please guide me where to look for the stuff like this.

Comment: You would have to extend the window manager. There are several of these, some very extensible, others not at all (unless you modify the source and build your own custom binary).

Answer (score 0):

You could also check out Devil's Pie which allows you to redefine how some windows behave. [Devil's Pie 2 website](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/)

Other than that, you'd have to customise the window manager (Metacity - Gnome 2 or Mutter - Gnome 3) yourself, which are in C, not python. Beware though, window manager hacking can drive people insane.